# Select only not selected combobox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

code with combobox generate function (working well)

```
<script>
$('#combos').on('change', '.combo', function() {
var selectedValue = $(this).val();

if (selectedValue !== '' && $(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;
$('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
newComboBox.find('option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
$('#combos').append(newComboBox);
}
});</script>
```

html and php (working well)

```
<form id="myForm">
<div id="combos"><select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
<option></option>
<?php
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=\"" .$r['id'] . "\">".$r['field'] ." ------</option>";
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<input type="button"  id="button_submit" value="Show">
</form>
```

This code should select only the non-selected comboboxes. But is not working. I think is only working for the 1st non-selected value that function found.
[Please see image](http://s11.postimage.org/48bdfwb1d/combo.png)

```
<script>
$('#button_submit').click(function() 
{

var combo_box_values = $('#combo1 option:not(:selected)').map(function () 
{
return parseInt(this.value);
}).get();

});
</script>
```

Question: Is it possible? Where is my code missing?

Cheers

**EDIT: source code**

```
<h4>Data Options</h4></center>
<div id="combos"><select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
<option></option>
<option value="1">uptime ------</option>
<option value="2">score ------</option>
    <option value="3">gender ------</option>
<option value="4">age ------</option>
    <option value="5">angry ------</option>
<option value="6">happy ------</option>
    <option value="7">sad ------</option>
<option value="8">surprised ------</option>
    <option value="9">location ------</option></select>
    <select id="combo2" class="combo parentCombo1" data-index="2">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">uptime ------</option>
    <option value="2">score ------</option>
    <option value="4">age ------</option>
    <option value="5">angry ------</option>
    <option value="6">happy ------</option>
    <option value="7">sad ------</option>
    <option value="8">surprised ------</option>
<option value="9">location ------</option></select>
    <select id="combo3" class="combo parentCombo1 parentCombo2" data-index="3">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">uptime ------</option>
    <option value="4">age ------</option>
    <option value="5">angry ------</option>
    <option value="6">happy ------</option>
    <option value="7">sad ------</option>
    <option value="8">surprised ------</option>
    <option value="9">location ------</option></select>
    <select id="combo4" class="combo parentCombo1 parentCombo2 parentCombo3" data-index="4">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">uptime ------</option>
    <option value="5">angry ------</option>
    <option value="6">happy ------</option>
    <option value="7">sad ------</option>
    <option value="8">surprised ------</option>
    <option value="9">location ------</option></select></div>
```

Comment: I think it is not searching into all comboboxes, just see the 1st then stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the leading part of the selector feeding the `.map()` needs to be `#combos` and not `#combo1` if you want to examine *all* the not selected options from all the `<select>` elements. For example,

```
var combo_box_values = $('#combos option:not(:selected)').map(function() {
    return parseInt(this.value);
}).get();
```

**Edit:** Based on feedback in the comments and an updated question this might work for you, however I'm sure a nicer solution exists as this just *feels* clunky.

```
$('#button_submit').click(function() {
  var combo_box_values = $('#combos .combo').filter(function() {
    return this.selectedIndex === 0;
  }).map(function () {

    return $('option:not(:selected)', this).map(function() {
      return parseInt(this.value);
    }).get();
  }).get();

  console.log(combo_box_values);
  return false;
});
```

I think the key part to understand is the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) which excludes the `<select>`s that the user has chosen an option for, leaving only those that have not been chosen. From there, it is a case of finding all the options that are not selected and extracting the value attribute.

If you want the *selected* options you could use `$('option', this)` instead of `$('option:not(:selected)', this)` in the code above.

In [**the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fnuke/) this should show `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` if *uptime* is selected in the first `<select>` and `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` if *surprised* is chosen in the first and *location* in the second.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @andyb, I've selected the 3 first options (1,2,3) and result was `NaN,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NaN,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NaN,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7,8,9`, should be only `NaN,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,5,6,7,8,9`. What could we do ?

Comment: Is there a full working example somewhere? The question contains PHP, rather than the generated HTML. I can't really help without looking at the same code you are using. Have you used [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) before?

Comment: Hm, i didnt find any exmaple :s I want the PHP ? It is simple, its just a query that returns `id` and `field`

Comment: I really need to see more code, for example the element with class = `parentCombo` is not in the question. Also, can you load the page in your browser and add the page source of the `<option>` elements to the question. I do not have the same code in the example I am working on as I've had to guess what your code looks like, so getting the correct result for you is difficult!

Comment: ive edited my post with source code. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: That's much better, I think I have a working example now. Could you just add a couple of examples of what the expected output will be? For example if I just select "uptime" in the first box, what should the alert be? And if I select 8 out of 9, what should the alert be?

Comment: only `uptime`, alert should be `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` which means, all the other options. If selec 8 or 9 , output should be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`. Im doing this in reverse, my ouput should be always the non-selected comboboxes. But if you know the solution for selected comboboxes its fine too :)

Comment: Updated my answer with something that I hope is close or solves the problem. I also made a demo in jsFiddle which maybe you could use to help describe the problem if my solution is not correct for your requirements :-)

Comment: it works almost great :p Only think is making some trouble is the fact of everytime user select combobox and then let it blank, comboboxes dont "close", they turn blank and cause troubles when submited :S

Comment: You could `.remove()` the box if a user chooses the _blank_ option. I am not sure how this might affect other parts of your system though. I think that might really be better asked as a new question it is a different problem to this question.